# Correct update nodejs and npm

Tags: node.js, npm

i am working on nuxtjs project since node v14 version. and now node is version v16. and I'm trying to update node to version v16. but after that my nuxt project error.
I'm confused, should I stick with v14 or upgrade?
what is the best way to update?

Comment: I think you should update all dependencies to the lastest as well. Check this: https://nodejs.dev/learn/update-all-the-nodejs-dependencies-to-their-latest-version

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is **recommended to update** to get the latest features and security updates.

---

To update Node.js and npm, go to [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/), download, and run the installer. The Node Package Manager should automatically be installed too.

Also, don't worry about removing the previous version; the installer takes care of that too.

---

To update your dependencies, update the `dependencies` and `devDependencies` fields to be the latest versions. For Nuxt.js, the latest version (at the time posted) is `v2.15.8`.

You can also use [`npm-check-updates`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates) to check for updates for all of your dependencies. Run the following commands to use it (running it in your project root directory).

```
$ npm install -g npm-check-updates
$ ncu -u
$ npm install
```

<sub>`ncu` is the command for `npm-check-updates`.</sub>

Also, you can update all of your dependencies manually to have the asterisk instead of the version, as so.

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "nuxt": "*"
  }
}
```

So, every time you run the command below, it will update the dependencies to the latest version.

```
$ npm install
```

Comment: thanks Arnav Thorat, its not fix for nuxt my project , but its help my confusion ... so thanks you so much..

Answer (score -2):

You can do it by installing n:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

It will install the current stable version of node.